# Unknow error in vuejs2

Tags: properties, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new in vuejs2. I am getting below error. Could anyone say why this error is coming ? Could you please provide any sample solution for this ?

[image]

**ModalBody.vue**

```
<script>  
    import SemanticModal from 'vue-ya-semantic-modal'

    export default {        
        components: { SemanticModal: SemanticModal() },
        name: 'ModalBody',
        props: {
            active1: {
                required: true
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**DataTable.vue**

```
<script>
import ModalBody from './ModalBody'

export default {
    components: { ModalBody },
    data: function () {
        return  {
            active1: false
        }
    },
    props: {
        columns: {
            required: true
        },
        gdata: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show () {
            this.active1 = true
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In vue prop mutating is anti pattern look [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated)

Comment: Thanks @CaShis for your reply. I updated my question.Could you please help me now ? Thanks.

Comment: try add default value for your prop

Answer (score 0):

Use computed Property(eg.isActive) for passing to children component

```
import ModalBody from './ModalBody'
export default {
    components: { ModalBody },
    data: function () {
        return  {
            active1: false
        }
    },
    props: {
        columns: {
            required: true
        },
        gdata: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed:{
       isActive (){
          return this.active1;
    },
    methods: {
        show () {
            this.active1 = true
        }
    },
}
```

And Pass this computed property to child component in template

```
<modal-body :active1='isActive'></modal-body>
```

By doing this it avoid mutation

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. I added child component to parent component as like below

```
<modal-body :active1="active1" @sendValue="active1 = $event"></modal-body>
```

I added `methods` like below in Parent Component

```
methods: {
            close() {
                this.$emit('sendValue', false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: props + event => v-model